# is it possible to log Gmail?

Tags: login, email, log, gmail

I want to know if it is possible to log Gmail using ubuntu in order to find out that who logged in ,

Honestly my gmail has been hacked and I don't know the password Right now .

Comment: I also recommend their two-factor authentication it's pretty safe and you could use a Password Safe like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/index.html) and just use random Passwords but you have to "like" that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible for you to log another machine using gmail. Google has multiple data-centers (with multiple independent network connections), your personal home network is likely to be irrelevant (and that is all you can conceivably log yourself). Also, you should probably use their [two-factor authentication](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744?hl=en) in future.

Comment: What does having multiple data centers have anything to do with this?

Comment: @rxt Edited to clarify.

Comment: Yes there is a log, although very limited. See my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You don't know your password - how do you want to login? 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/50270?hl=en

Go to the police and get a warrant to let google unlock your account.

Whenever you can login again: Use 2-factor login, renew your password, check mail forward to unknown addresses, check who is granted access to your account.

When logged in, looked in the bottom right corner. There is a details link, which shows a list of activity, with ip addresses.

Comment: He said "log", not "login".

Comment: He says he doesn't know his password right now. Without password, no login, no logging!